# What is the most efficent way to handle DirectX 11 texture Image Stride

Tags: windows, rust, directx

I'm trying to build a screen capture library using Windows Graphics Capture Api ([windows-capture](https://github.com/NiiightmareXD/windows-capture)) but there is a problem handling the mapped buffer [image stride](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/image-stride) which is the empty buffer at the end of each RowPitch currently I handle it like this:

```rs
            let row_size = self.width as usize * std::mem::size_of::<Rgba>();

            for i in 0..self.height {
                unsafe {
                    ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(
                        mapped_resource
                            .pData
                            .add((i * mapped_resource.RowPitch) as usize)
                            as *mut u8,
                        self.buffer.add(i as usize * row_size),
                        row_size,
                    )
                };
            }
```

which is kinda slow (4ms on my CPU) is there anyway to do it on the GPU so it will be faster I tried using compute shader but it didn't work?

I basically want the fastest way to get the screen pixel data buffer in a &[u8].

Thanks for helping.

Comment: `Map` might be blocking while the data is being copied from the GPU to CPU. Try copying first to `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` buffer, then map the staging buffer. However, you will need to synchronise i.e. use a fence. to make sure the copy is finished before mapping

Comment: @TomHuntington the map and the copy works but the problem is handling image strides is slow.

Comment: I hear you but I don't think you understand the difference between `Map`ping `D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT` vs `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` resources. `D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT` is gpu backed memory and when mapped, the runtime creates cpu backed memory copies from gpu to cpu, BLOCKS for the copy to finish, then gives you the pointer. To avoid the blocking you need to copy to a `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` resource and map that

Comment: @TomHuntington I am using a D3D11_USAGE_STAGING texture and then copy the resource and then map it

Comment: Hmm, Are you sure the D3D11 copy has finished before you call `ptr::copy_nonoverlapping`. Something funny might be going on see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75871029/11998382

Comment: Perhaps try timing the code above without ever copying to the staging texture, Perhaps, try replacing `mapped_resource` with just a normal buffer (or whatever rust calls it). Perhaps you timing is wrong, 4ms is way to slow

Answer (score 0):

To speed up the process of transferring screen pixel data from the Windows Graphics Capture API to your buffer, employing GPU-based techniques might not be the most direct approach. Typically, GPU techniques are used for processing and rendering rather than direct memory manipulation.

Try:

```
use std::ptr;
use std::mem;

let row_size = self.width as usize * mem::size_of::<Rgba>();

for i in 0..self.height {
    let src = mapped_resource.pData.add((i * mapped_resource.RowPitch) as usize) as *const u8;
    let dest = self.buffer.add(i as usize * row_size);

    unsafe {
        // Using memcpy for optimized memory copy
        ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(src, dest as *mut u8, row_size);
    }
}
```

If this solution does not work try the following:

- **Multithreading**: If not implemented, consider parallelizing the memory copy operation across multiple threads.
- **Batch Processing**: Try optimizing how the captured screen data is retrieved or buffered.
- **Direct Memory Mapping**: Check if direct memory mapping can be leveraged directly from the GPU to your buffer.